# How to limit browse button to valid image files only 

Tags: html, file, upload

I want that whenever we click on browser button to upload so only image file is comes automatically instead of other file extension

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict the upload, with just using HTML. There are two ways AFAIK

- Read the file types and deny, after the form is submitted at the back end.
- Use plugins like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to restrict while selecting the file